# Is handling of curly braces in javascript regex is the same across all modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, regex

Curly braces in JavaScript regex is used to denote quantifiers. So writing

```
a{2,4}
```

will match aa, aaa and aaaa. But if you mistype this quantifier like this:

```
x{1,x}
```

It will match the literal text "x{1,x}", at least in Firefox.

Is this behavior common to modern browsers?

The ECMA standard prohibits this behavior and requires the escaping of the braces.

(Background: I have to write a parser for javascript regexes at work.)

Comment: Eww... Nice bug! Does it happen when you invoke `new RegExp()`, `//` or both?

Comment: Where does it say about the requirement of escaping in te specification? The relevant defition of `QuantifierPrefix` is `{ DecimalDigits , DecimalDigits }`, so `{1,x}` should not be interpreted as a quantifier because `x` is not a `DecimalDigit` - thus the behaviour seems consistent with the specs.

Comment: `PatternCharacter is
SourceCharacter but not one of
^ $ \ . * + ? (
) [ ] { } |`   So curly braces cannot be a pattern character.

Comment: The `IdentityEscape` rule allows escaping the curly braces.

Comment: @Calmarius: Good catch. I'm not sure what the supposed behaviour is according to the specification, since it can neither be a quantifier nor a regular character.

Comment: @pimvdb It can neither be a quantifier nor a regular character, this means the regex is ill formed, the implementation should report an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for JavaScript and browsers, but this is the behaviour I would have expected and that I have seen in the past in regular expressions.

So I tested different regex engines on their behaviour:

- **C#**: behaves this way
- **Perl**: behaves this way
- **Python**: behaves this way
- **PHP**: behaves this way
- **Java**: throws an Exception